# Dynamic paperheight (crop to content)

Tags: geometry

Is it possible to have the paperheight of the document be determined automatically to fit the content?

A small working example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,oneside]{book}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\geometry{paperwidth=8cm, paperheight=10cm,vmargin=0.7cm, hmargin=0.7cm}

%\geometry{paperwidth=8cm, paperheight=\fill,vmargin=0.7cm, hmargin=0.7cm}

\pagenumbering{gobble}

\begin{document}
  \noindent
  \centering
  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{X r}
    entry & 1 \\
    entry & 2 \\
    entry & 3 \\
    entry & 4 \\
    entry & 5 \\
    entry & 6 \\
%   \input{data}
  \end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

generates this

[image: example]

Now the real world example uses a `\input{}` to include a data.tex file which contains any number of entries.

The goal is to have the final pdf be a single page that is cropped to the content and thus the `\paperheight` property needs to be something that makes the content fit in a single page with the correct `hmargin` and `vmargin`

With the desired result being something like this:

[image: desired]

Would this be possible within LaTeX or are there tools that can do this as a postprocessing step?

Comment: Have you tried `standalone` document class?

Comment: Why not just run the result through `pdfcrop` afterwards.

Comment: @AlexG I have not, I did not even know of its existence. Will check it out now

Comment: @daleif I could but I'm was looking if it was possible within LaTeX itself first. Also, doing it with pdfcrop still requires me to specify a pageheight that is large enough to fit all the content and without knowing beforehand the size of the number of entries how would I determine this pageheight? I could specify a ridiculously large pageheight but surely there has to be a better way

Comment: Then it might be better to explain what exactly this is going to be used for. Then it might be easier to give you a more accurate advise.

Answer (score 1):

Based on AlexG suggestion of using the standalone document class, here is the code that I use now for anyone that stumbles upon this in the future...

```
\documentclass[10pt, border=0.7cm, preview, varwidth=8cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}
  \noindent
  \centering
  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{X r}
    entry & 1 \\
    entry & 2 \\
    entry & 3 \\
    entry & 4 \\
    entry & 5 \\
    entry & 6 \\
%   \input{data}
  \end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

A few notes regarding this, compared to my starting point. Instead of using the geometry package to specify the paperwidth use the varwidth of the standalone class and instead of the margins from geometry package use the border property in the standalone class

Comment: Congratulations!!!